# Methods are not visible in class diagram UMLDesigner 7.1

Tags: eclipse-sirius, uml-designer

I am using the UMLDesigner Sirius version 7.1 and by far a great tool. I had to switch my workspace and reimport my project into the new workspace. I am currently working on a class diagram. Everytime when i am creating a new method in a class it stays invisible. Do i miss something or is it a bug?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found what is the "problem" here. The concerned diagram is not synchronized (right-click on the diagram background and click on the "unsynchronized" menu entry. If this option is disabled (that is the default state of Class diagrams), then everything goes back to the "classic" behavior.
So there is no bug here.